# Why do Rails /lib modules prevent gem modules from loading?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module

The title of this question may need renaming. Any suggestions?

In my Rails application there was an old Module in the /lib folder called foo_blaster.rb. I then installed my gem named foo_blaster.rb. None of the code in the gem executed until I deleted the original FooBlaster module. Why is this? Shouldn't Ruby combine the two Modules?

The Modules are the same

```
# lib/foo_blaster.rb
module FooBlaster
  class Characters
    puts "some characters"
  end
end

# foo_blaster gem files
module FooBlaster
   class Users
   end
end

FooBlaster::Characters #=> some characters
FooBlaster::Users #=> NameError: uninitialized constant FooBlaster::Users
```

What am I missing here?

Rails 2.3.18,
Ruby 1.8.7-p358

Comment: in your Gemfile, can you try 'gem :foo_blaster, :require => "foo_blaster"' --- that might keep clear of Rails Autoloading

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you open up a console (with `script/console`) and examine the `$LOAD_PATH` variable, you should see something resembling this:

```
>> $LOAD_PATH
[
  # some entries...
  [12] "/your/rails/root/app",
  [13] "/your/rails/root/app/controllers",
  [14] "/your/rails/root/app/models",
  [15] "/your/rails/root/app/helpers",
  [16] "/your/rails/root/lib",
  # more entries...
  [27] "/your/ruby/path/lib/ruby/1.8/gems/foo_blaster-0.0.1/lib"
  # rest of entries
]
```

When you `require 'foo_blaster'` (which may be done implicitly by Rails, Bundler, or perhaps some other means), Ruby  searches the locations in `$LOAD_PATH` sequentially until it finds the file foo_blaster.rb, loads that file, and stops.  In your case, it finds the file in your application's /lib directory.  The file from your gem will never be loaded.

If you want to load both files, all you have to do is give them different names and make sure to `require` them both.  For instance, you might rename the file in your application to foo_blaster_extensions.rb, then add an initializer to load it:

```
# config/initializers/extend_foo_blaster.rb
require 'foo_blaster_extensions'
```

Comment: This makes perfect sense. Thanks for the insight into the $LOAD_PATH of Rails. I would up vote this, but I don't have enough reputation yet.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a case when you need same name file in your core app. You should follow best practices while creating gem i.e., you should namespace your gem. So in that case no conflicts will occur with core application.